# How to get or call secrets from hashicorp vault using Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I'm having a use case with me.

currently, I'm using helm over **on premise Kubernetes cluster** where all of my environment variables and secrets are stored in helm itself but now I want to store them in hashicorp vault.

as of now its totaly new for me and i'm having some hard time to make it work.

so the use case is something like,
how we can use **hashicorp vault** to store the values which are getting use by Helm as of now.
Once we store the values which we want how we can call them by using **helm** it self only.

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/Just-Insane/helm-vault)?

Comment: I did try to implement this but ended up being haaaaa leave it will do something else
i'm struggling since last 15 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use external-secrets.io to mount secrets from Hashicorp Vault as Kubernetes secrets and consume them as environment variables in a pod, you can follow these steps:

1. Install external-secrets.io into your Kubernetes cluster:

```
kubectl apply -f https://external-secrets.io/install
```

2. Create a Kubernetes secret backed by Vault:

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
spec:
  provider: hashivault
  hashivault:
    path: secret/myapp
  data:
    - key: username
      name: USERNAME
    - key: password
      name: PASSWORD
```

3. Create a Kubernetes deployment that consumes the secret:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp:latest
        env:
        - name: USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysecret
              key: USERNAME
        - name: PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysecret
              key: PASSWORD
```

4. Apply the deployment:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

This will mount the secrets from Vault into a Kubernetes secret, and then consume the secrets as environment variables in the pod. You can access the values of the secrets in your application as `os.getenv("USERNAME")` and `os.getenv("PASSWORD")`.

Note: You will need to have the Hashicorp Vault CLI installed and configured, and have access to the Vault server, in order to complete these steps.